# How do i disable the timestamps in terminal

Tags: npm, zsh, nuxt3

I have a nuxt 3 project and I run `npm run dev` in the terminal, but almost every line has a timestamp on the right, this gets in the way when I work on a small resolution, I want to disable or hide those timestamps.

I am not sure if they come from npm or zsh, I tried multiple solutions but cannot find an answer.

One of the solutions got me to change `~/.zshrc` by adding this line `PS1="%1~ %# "` which helped shorten the initial prompt to not show the full path, which is a good start, but I have no idea how to tackle the timestamps.

Thank you!

[image: npm run dev]